# JavaScript ask for problem i don't understand what's mean in programming

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

arr.sort((a, b) => a < b ?
1 : a > b ? -1 : 0);
'I don't understand what's meaning double dot between 1 and a ?

Comment: [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) I recommend using also `(` and `)`

Comment: You would be far more able to find the appropriate information if you knew the names of the symbols you're looking at - that "double dot" is a _colon_. You can also use https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/3001761.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `python-3.x` so why the tag?

Answer (score 0):

Expresion `a < b ? 1 : a > b ? -1 : 0` is equivalent to:

```
if (a < b) {
    return 1
} else {
    if (a > b) {
        return -1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

The colon `:` essentialy means else in `ternary operator`

`condition` ? `return this if the condition is true` : `return if the condition is false`